# Missing upload related browse option in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm working on tinymce rich text editor.
I had used the fileupload option in menu of rich text.
Unfortunately I was not ale to get the browse option for the file upload pop-up window.

[image: Without browse option]

Expected Result :
taken from https://codepen.io/nirajmchauhan/pen/EjQLpV
[image: Expected result]

My code :

```
function loadTinyMCEEditor() {
        tinyMCE.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            theme: "modern",
            menu: { // this is the complete default configuration
                file: { title: 'File', items: 'newdocument' },
                edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall' },

                insert: { title: 'Insert', items: 'link media | template hr' },
                view: { title: 'View', items: 'visualaid' },
                format: { title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat' },

                tools: { title: 'Tools', items: 'spellchecker code' }
            },
            plugins: [
  "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
  "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",

            ],
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",

            toolbar_items_size: 'small',
            setup: function (ed) {
                ed.on('blur', function (x,e) {
                    debugger;
                    var x = $(x.target.editorContainer).find('iframe')[0];
                    var idis = $(x).attr('id');
                    var fields = idis.split('_');

                    var bp = fields[2];
                    var bplevel = fields[3];
                    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
                    var doc = document.getElementById(idis).contentDocument;
                    var g = doc.all[0]
                    var val = g.innerHTML
                    AutoSaveLevel(val, bp, bplevel);
                    console.log('blur event fired.');
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder icon is created when the `file_picker_callback:` field is defined in the `tiny.init()` configuration object.

From the [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#file_picker_callback):

> Once you define `file_picker_callback`, small browse button will appear along the fields of supported file types (see file_picker_types).